# How to open a file starting with dash via xdg-open

Tags: command-line, filenames, xdg-open

Usually, a double dash separates options from filenames, but xdg-open does not care:

```bash
❯ xdg-open -headlinesAfter.epub
xdg-open: unexpected option '-headlinesAfter.epub'
Try 'xdg-open --help' for more information.
❯ xdg-open -- -headlinesAfter.epub
xdg-open: unexpected option '--'
Try 'xdg-open --help' for more information.
```

Is there any other way?

Comment: see https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xdg/xdg-utils/-/issues/185

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open the file by adding `./`:

```
xdg-open ./-headlinesAfter.epub
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that `xdg-open` is a shell script, so you can fix it yourself. Put a fixed version of it in a file of the same name in a personal directory in your PATH. A fix might be to simply not test for `-*` options, since none are supported. To do so remove the lines:

```
      -*)
        exit_failure_syntax "unexpected option '$parm'"
        ;;
```